# How to add buttons to a customized RViz panel

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am sub-classing `RViz` to create a small customized panel. I found [this](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html) and started doing this tutorial. However I was trying to implement a couple of buttons. I did using `getNumViews()` function available [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rviz/html/c++/classrviz_1_1ViewManager.html#a2f029f5bc775b8e211b9254b1bd36bc8).
As I click on the button nothing happens and the view never changes.
Is there something I am missing? Thanks for shedding light on this issues.
Below the code:

**myviz.h**

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    void switchToTopView(QString viewName);
    void switchToSideView(QString viewName);

private:
    QString sideView = "Side View";
    QString topView = "Top View";
```

**myviz.cpp**

```
MyViz::MyViz(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

// Setting up constructor

    QPushButton *topViewBtn = new QPushButton("Top View");
    QPushButton *sideViewBtn = new QPushButton("Side View");


    QGridLayout* control_layout = new QGridLayout();
    control_layout->addWidget(topViewBtn, 3, 0);
    control_layout->addWidget(sideViewBtn, 3, 1);

    // construct lay-out and render panels next to each other
    render_panel = new rviz::RenderPanel();

    connect(topViewBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(switchToTopView(QString("Top View"))));
    connect(sideViewBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(switchToSideView(QString("Side View"))));

// Other operations

}

void MyViz::switchToTopView(QString viewName)
{
    topView = viewName;
    view_man = manager->getViewManager();
    view_man->getNumViews();
    view_man->getViewAt(1)->getName() = topView;
    view_man->setCurrentFrom(view_man->getViewAt(1));
}

void MyViz::switchToSideView(QString viewName)
{
    sideView = viewName;
    view_man = manager->getViewManager();
    view_man->getNumViews();
    view_man->getViewAt(2)->getName() = sideView;
    view_man->setCurrentFrom(view_man->getViewAt(2));
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326099/how-to-add-buttons-to-a-customized-rviz-panel/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
I have not looked into your problem in detail, but this:

```
view_man->getViewAt(1)->getName() == topView;
```

is a boolean expression, comparing `topView` to whatever is returned by `view_man->getViewAt(1)->getName()`.

Did you mean to assign `topView` to `view_man->getViewAt(1)->getName()`? Then you'd have to remove a `=`.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-06-18**:
Thanks gvdhoorn for taking the time to read the question. Yes your comment is right and I fixed it to the code but I now get the `QObject::connect: No such slot MyViz::switchToTopView(QString("Top View"))` error from compiler and don't understand why. And also `QObject::connect: No such slot MyViz::switchToTopView(QString("Side View"))`

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-06-18**:
I went through the official documentation about that and I thought that the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` statement should have been correct. Am I missing something?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
I've not looked at this at all, so I wouldn't be able to help you unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the answer to this question and why there was no connection between `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` and wanted to share in case someone has my same problem.
The small issue was the different notation between `C++11` and `C++17` and about my question the correct answer is the notation below:

```
QObject::connect( topViewBtn1, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){
    switchToTopView(QString("Top View"));
});
```

As also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612030/qt-qobjectconnect-no-such-slot)
I hope this could be helpful for others.

---

Originally posted by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) with karma: 108 on 2019-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0